# Allen Hatcher Algebraic Topology Section 1.3 Exercise 27 (1.3.27)

Tags: algebraic-topology

For a universal cover $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$ we have two actions of
  $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ on the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$, namely the action given
  by lifting loops at $x_0$ and the action given by restricting deck
  transformations to the fiber. Are these two actions the same when
  $X=S^1\vee S^1$ or $X=S^1\times S^1$? Do the actions always agree
  when $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is abelian?